# Screenshot not written correctly using "screencap -p" shell command in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, shell, xamarin.android, screenshot

I want to programmatically take a screenshot of my app and for certain reasons (using OpenGl SurfaceView to name one) I dont want to use the usually named methods like using the views drawing cache. I tested the *screencap -p* shell command using adb and it worked perfectly. But if I execute the command from my Xamarin Android app using the following code:

```
Java.Lang.Process process;
process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("screencap -p /sdcard/test.png");
process.WaitFor();
```

the test.png file is created but only 12B in size and obviously not showing an image (only grey with a circled ! sign). I don't have a rooted device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 btw) but since the command is working via adb shell without and su or root stuff I would think it could also work from within the app.

So my questions are: Is it possible to take a screenshot using the "screencap -p" shell command from within an application on a device that is not rooted?
If the answer is yes, why do I encounter corrupted image files? What could be possible causes for this and how to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to fully qualify screencap, so I believe you can just do the following:

```
Java.Lang.Process process;
process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/test.png");
process.WaitFor();
```

I'm basing that on an example java class that's available to view on [GitHub here](https://github.com/weimingtom/wmt_android_screenshot/blob/master/src/com/poofinc/screenshot/ScreenshotService.java). Obviously just convert from Java to Xamarin where appropriate.

Interestingly it looks like they try to get sudo privileges if it fails to write on the first try using:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but that did not help. Still the same behaviour using the full path

Comment: Did you have much luck looking at that java service I linked in the GitHub because it looks like that's exactly what you're trying to do but just needs converting to xamarin

Comment: I did have a look, but I am a little skeptical about it. The code is very messy and seems to follow some kind of shotgun approach. I also doubt that the su command would work, because using it via adb shell gives me an "command not found" error. I might give it a shot anyway.

Comment: @T_D what you're after is definitely possible, Snapchat uses screenshots on android rather than the cameras for various performance and device restriction reasons. I'll take another look tomorrow. If you've managed to try anything else or rule anything out pop it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the device log via `adb logcat` when I was taking the screenshot. The problem seems to be that you need the android permission "READ_FRAME_BUFFER". But this permission is only available for system apps. So in conclusion I would say that it is simply not possible for my circumstances where I dont have a rooted device. With a rooted device the "su" approach probably would work.